# Item::contains always returns true

Tags: qt, qml

`Item::contains` always seems to return true regardless of input:

```
import QtQuick 2.3

Rectangle {
    width: 400
    height: 400
    color: "green"

    Rectangle {
        id: block
        width: 50
        height: 50
        color: "red"

        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent

        onClicked: {
            var pnt = mapToItem( block, mouse.x, mouse.y );
            console.log( "pnt x:", pnt.x, "y:", pnt.y );
            if ( block.contains( pnt ) ) {
                console.log( "Inside" );
            } else {
                console.log( "Outside" );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running this and clicking randomly gives output like this:

```
qml: pnt x: 104 y: 102
qml: Inside
qml: pnt x: -113 y: -101
qml: Inside
qml: pnt x: -105 y: 111
qml: Inside
qml: pnt x: 120 y: -62
qml: Inside
```

As you can see `Inside` is printed even when the input is outside the inner block.  Is there something I'm not understanding about `Item::contains`?

### Edit

If I throw together a basic rectangular `contains` method:

```
function myContains( pnt ) {
    return pnt.x >= 0 && pnt.x < block.width &&
           pnt.y >= 0 && pnt.y < block.height;
}
```

It works fine, so there's nothing wrong with the `block` position and size.  The default `QQuickItem::contains(..)` method is supposed to just use a basic local coord rectangular test like the above too.

### Edit2

As noted by @Mitch it seems that the `object` returned by `Item::mapToItem(..)` is not being converted to a `QPointF` on the C++ side.  The solution is to push the converted coords into a `Qt.point` before calling `Item::contains`:

```
...
if ( block.contains( Qt.point( pnt.x, pnt.y ) ) ) {
...
```

Comment: @vincentdeg "What happens in the mapToItem method?" -> https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#mapToItem-method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bug. If you add a debug statement to `QQuickItem::contains()`, you can see that the point is incorrectly converted to `{0, 0}`:

```
--- a/src/quick/items/qquickitem.cpp
+++ b/src/quick/items/qquickitem.cpp
@@ -6922,6 +6922,7 @@ void QQuickItem::setKeepTouchGrab(bool keep)
 bool QQuickItem::contains(const QPointF &point) const
 {
     Q_D(const QQuickItem);
+    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << point;
     return QRectF(0, 0, d->width, d->height).contains(point);
 }
```

Output:

```
qml: pnt x: 79 y: 74
bool __thiscall QQuickItem::contains(const class QPointF &) const QPointF(0,0)
qml: Inside
```

Unfortunately (and very surprisingly) the tests don't account for this, as they [only test](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtdeclarative/source/5a9f0131f8c0b7424a4d323b0f65237206be45ea:tests/auto/quick/qquickitem2/tst_qquickitem.cpp#L247) a custom `contains` function, and do so in C++.

Comment: I browsed the C++ source but couldn't see anything wrong with it, I see now that the problem is occurring at the QML/C++ boundary.  I've created a bug report here: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-41452